# How do I find the transform matrix which map two point to another two point?

Tags: animation, math

Assume I have an animation that moves from ptA to ptB, ptA and ptB is defined in the entity's local space.
What I want to do is make this entity move from ptAA to ptBB when I play the same animation, ptAA and ptBB is in world space.

So, if I start from ptAA and play the animation, there must be a transform matrix that could map every point in the animation, ie ptA and ptB, to ptAA and ptBB, the final result is the entity will be at ptBB when the animation finished.

Comment: That's supposed to be 3D rotation + stretch?

Comment: @mikuszefski yes

Comment: Well, I'd use a quaternion for rotation. There are, however, infinite possibilities to rotate. Shortest rotation is with the axis perpendicular on the plane of source and target vector. You also have infinite possibilities of stretching, even when (most likely) restricting to monotonous functions. Choices might be linear, cubic etc.